# Sanitizing strings to make them URL and filename safe?

Tags: php, url, filenames, sanitization

I am trying to come up with a function that does a good job of sanitizing certain strings so that they are safe to use in the URL (like a post slug) and also safe to use as file names. For example, when someone uploads a file I want to make sure that I remove all dangerous characters from the name.

So far I have come up with the following function which I hope solves this problem and allows foreign UTF-8 data also.

```
/**
 * Convert a string to the file/URL safe "slug" form
 *
 * @param string $string the string to clean
 * @param bool $is_filename TRUE will allow additional filename characters
 * @return string
 */
function sanitize($string = '', $is_filename = FALSE)
{
 // Replace all weird characters with dashes
 $string = preg_replace('/[^\w\-'. ($is_filename ? '~_\.' : ''). ']+/u', '-', $string);

 // Only allow one dash separator at a time (and make string lowercase)
 return mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/--+/u', '-', $string), 'UTF-8');
}
```

**Does anyone have any tricky sample data I can run against this - or know of a better way to safeguard our apps from bad names?**

*$is-filename allows some additional characters like temp vim files*

*update: removed the star character since I could not think of a valid use*

Comment: You better remove everything except [\w.-]

Comment: You may find the [Normalizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) and the comments on it useful.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Some observations on your solution:

1. 'u' at the end of your pattern means that the **pattern**, and not the text it's matching will be interpreted as UTF-8 (I presume you assumed the latter?).
2. \w matches the underscore character. You specifically include it for files which leads to the assumption that you don't want them in URLs, but in the code you have URLs will be permitted to include an underscore.
3. The inclusion of "foreign UTF-8" seems to be locale-dependent. It's not clear whether this is the locale of the server or client. From the PHP docs:

> > A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.

#### Creating the slug

You probably shouldn't include accented etc. characters in your post slug since, technically, they should be percent encoded (per URL encoding rules) so you'll have ugly looking URLs.

So, if I were you, after lowercasing, I'd convert any 'special' characters to their equivalent  (e.g. é -> e) and replace non [a-z] characters with '-', limiting to runs of a single '-' as you've done. There's an implementation of converting special characters here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130208144021/http://neo22s.com/slug

#### Sanitization in general

OWASP have a PHP implementation of their Enterprise Security API which among other things includes methods for safe encoding and decoding input and output in your application.

The Encoder interface provides:

```
canonicalize (string $input, [bool $strict = true])
decodeFromBase64 (string $input)
decodeFromURL (string $input)
encodeForBase64 (string $input, [bool $wrap = false])
encodeForCSS (string $input)
encodeForHTML (string $input)
encodeForHTMLAttribute (string $input)
encodeForJavaScript (string $input)
encodeForOS (Codec $codec, string $input)
encodeForSQL (Codec $codec, string $input)
encodeForURL (string $input)
encodeForVBScript (string $input)
encodeForXML (string $input)
encodeForXMLAttribute (string $input)
encodeForXPath (string $input)
```

https://github.com/OWASP/PHP-ESAPI
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API

Comment: You are correct about my assumption of the "u" modifier - I thought that it was for the text. I also forgot about the \w modifier including the underscore. I would normally convert all accented characters to ASCII - but I want this to work for other languages as well. I was assuming that there would be some kind of UTF-8 safe way that any character of a language could be used in a URL slug or filename so that even Arabic titles would work. After all, linux supports UTF-8 filenames and browsers *should* encode HTML links as needed. Big thanks for your input here.

Comment: On second thought, you're actually right, but it's not just an issue with the browser encoding the links correctly. 

The easiest way to achieve close to what you want is to map non-ASCII characters to their closest ASCII equivalent and then URL-encode your link in the HTML body.

The hard way is to ensure consistent UTF-8 encoding (or UTF-16, I think for some Chinese dialects) from your data store, through your webserver, application layer (PHP), page content, web browser and **not** urlencode your urls (but still strip 'undesirable' chars). This will give you nice non-encoded links and URLs.

Comment: Good advice. I'm going to try to create a pure UTF-8 environment. Then, taking a several strings from non-ASCII languages, I'll remove dangerous chars (./;:etc...) and creating files and then HTML links to those files to see if I can click them and see if all this works. If not then I'll probably have to drop back to (raw)?urlencode() to allow UTF-8. I'll post back results here.

Comment: I created a file called `สังเวช พระปกเกศกองบู๊กู้ขึ้นใหม่.txt` and then created a UTF-8 HTML file with a link to it. Amazingly it worked - even on windows! However, I then had PHP `file_put_contents('สังเวช พระปกเกศกองบู๊กู้ขึ้นใหม่.txt')` and it failed creating a bazaar filename from that string. Then I tried to create it with `fopen()` and got the same messed up filename. So apparently PHP (on windows at least) is incapable of creating UTF-8 filenames. http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46990&thanks=6

Comment: I award this answer because it got me thinking the most and also included a useful link to a project I never heard of that is worth looking into. I'll post once I find a the answer though.

Comment: New link to OWASP PHP ESAPI: [https://github.com/OWASP/PHP-ESAPI](https://github.com/OWASP/PHP-ESAPI)

Answer (score 91):

I found this larger function in the [Chyrp](https://github.com/vito/chyrp/blob/35c646dda657300b345a233ab10eaca7ccd4ec10/includes/helpers.php#L515) code:

```
/**
 * Function: sanitize
 * Returns a sanitized string, typically for URLs.
 *
 * Parameters:
 *     $string - The string to sanitize.
 *     $force_lowercase - Force the string to lowercase?
 *     $anal - If set to *true*, will remove all non-alphanumeric characters.
 */
function sanitize($string, $force_lowercase = true, $anal = false) {
    $strip = array("~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "=", "+", "[", "{", "]",
                   "}", "\\", "|", ";", ":", "\"", "'", "&#8216;", "&#8217;", "&#8220;", "&#8221;", "&#8211;", "&#8212;",
                   "â€”", "â€“", ",", "<", ".", ">", "/", "?");
    $clean = trim(str_replace($strip, "", strip_tags($string)));
    $clean = preg_replace('/\s+/', "-", $clean);
    $clean = ($anal) ? preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $clean) : $clean ;
    return ($force_lowercase) ?
        (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) ?
            mb_strtolower($clean, 'UTF-8') :
            strtolower($clean) :
        $clean;
}
```

and this one in the [wordpress](http://wordpress.org) code

```
/**
 * Sanitizes a filename replacing whitespace with dashes
 *
 * Removes special characters that are illegal in filenames on certain
 * operating systems and special characters requiring special escaping
 * to manipulate at the command line. Replaces spaces and consecutive
 * dashes with a single dash. Trim period, dash and underscore from beginning
 * and end of filename.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 *
 * @param string $filename The filename to be sanitized
 * @return string The sanitized filename
 */
function sanitize_file_name( $filename ) {
    $filename_raw = $filename;
    $special_chars = array("?", "[", "]", "/", "\\", "=", "<", ">", ":", ";", ",", "'", "\"", "&", "$", "#", "*", "(", ")", "|", "~", "`", "!", "{", "}");
    $special_chars = apply_filters('sanitize_file_name_chars', $special_chars, $filename_raw);
    $filename = str_replace($special_chars, '', $filename);
    $filename = preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', $filename);
    $filename = trim($filename, '.-_');
    return apply_filters('sanitize_file_name', $filename, $filename_raw);
}
```

### Update Sept 2012

[Alix Axel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89771/alix-axel) has done some incredible work in this area. His phunction framework includes several great text filters and transformations.

- [Unaccent](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction/Text.php#L297)
- [Slug](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction/Text.php#L249)
- [Filter](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction.php#L301)

Comment: The WordPress code isn't portable as it makes use of `apply_filters`

Comment: Note that the wordpress version replaces `/[\s-]+/` with `-` which is better than the first version (which replaces only `/\s+/`) that can cause multiple dashes in a row

Comment: Just for reference wordpress apply_filters can be found [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/plugin.php#L0) and sanitize_file_name over [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L0).

Comment: what about multiple spaces? Replace

Comment: The $anal -variable sounds very frightening to me with the force-option.

Comment: **There was update 2.8.0**

 - Rel - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_file_name/

Answer (score 30):

This should make your filenames safe...

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/\.[\.]+/', '/[^\w_\.\-]/'), array('_', '.', ''), $string);
```

and a deeper solution to this is:

```
// Remove special accented characters - ie. sí.
$clean_name = strtr($string, array('Š' => 'S','Ž' => 'Z','š' => 's','ž' => 'z','Ÿ' => 'Y','À' => 'A','Á' => 'A','Â' => 'A','Ã' => 'A','Ä' => 'A','Å' => 'A','Ç' => 'C','È' => 'E','É' => 'E','Ê' => 'E','Ë' => 'E','Ì' => 'I','Í' => 'I','Î' => 'I','Ï' => 'I','Ñ' => 'N','Ò' => 'O','Ó' => 'O','Ô' => 'O','Õ' => 'O','Ö' => 'O','Ø' => 'O','Ù' => 'U','Ú' => 'U','Û' => 'U','Ü' => 'U','Ý' => 'Y','à' => 'a','á' => 'a','â' => 'a','ã' => 'a','ä' => 'a','å' => 'a','ç' => 'c','è' => 'e','é' => 'e','ê' => 'e','ë' => 'e','ì' => 'i','í' => 'i','î' => 'i','ï' => 'i','ñ' => 'n','ò' => 'o','ó' => 'o','ô' => 'o','õ' => 'o','ö' => 'o','ø' => 'o','ù' => 'u','ú' => 'u','û' => 'u','ü' => 'u','ý' => 'y','ÿ' => 'y'));
$clean_name = strtr($clean_name, array('Þ' => 'TH', 'þ' => 'th', 'Ð' => 'DH', 'ð' => 'dh', 'ß' => 'ss', 'Œ' => 'OE', 'œ' => 'oe', 'Æ' => 'AE', 'æ' => 'ae', 'µ' => 'u'));

$clean_name = preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/\.[\.]+/', '/[^\w_\.\-]/'), array('_', '.', ''), $clean_name);
```

This assumes that you want a dot in the filename.
if you want it transferred to lowercase, just use

```
$clean_name = strtolower($clean_name);
```

for the last line.

Comment: Still missing some Czech and Slovak characters: `'ľ' => 'l', 'Ľ' => 'L', 'č' => 'c', 'Č' => 'C', 'ť' => 't', 'Ť' => 'T', 'ň' => 'n', 'Ň' => 'N', 'ĺ' => 'l', 'Ĺ' => 'L', 'Ř' => 'R', 'ř' => 'r', 'ě' => 'e', 'Ě' => 'E', 'ů' => 'u', 'Ů' => 'U'`

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
function normal_chars($string)
{
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $string = preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $string);
    $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $string = preg_replace(array('~[^0-9a-z]~i', '~[ -]+~'), ' ', $string);

    return trim($string, ' -');
}

Examples:

echo normal_chars('Álix----_Ãxel!?!?'); // Alix Axel
echo normal_chars('áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ'); // aeiouAEIOU
echo normal_chars('üÿÄËÏÖÜŸåÅ'); // uyAEIOUYaA
```

Based on the selected answer in this thread: [URL Friendly Username in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php)

Comment: Very nice - I have never seen this done without a translation table (like wordpress uses). However, I don't think this function is enough as-is since it only translates special characters but does not remove dangerous characters. Maybe it can be *added to one above*...

Comment: Ha! That entity encoding hack is sweet! Though it's not at all clear at first glance how this method does what it does.

There's a problem though. Won't "Frédéric & Éric" turn into "Frederic amp Eric"?

Comment: @AlanDonnelly: Indeed, I've updated the function in my original answer (check the link), the `trim()` should also be `trim($string, '-')`.

Comment: @Xeoncross: The last `preg_replace()` should remove all dangerous chars.

Comment: @AlixAxel, your just everywhere aren't you. I was just reading over the PHP AWS SDK and they had some of your code for UUID's. The awesome code of phunction is just hard to beat.

Comment: @Xeoncross: Thanks for letting me know, wasn't even aware of that! =)

Comment: I wanted to use this to convert a bunch of TV episode names into Windows-based filenames, keeping their extensions, square brackets, dashes and single quotes, and changing colons to dots or dashes where appropriate. So here's my version: http://pastebin.com/0CsEV0Ax

Comment: At 425ms it's pretty slow, just FYI

Answer (score 13):

*This isn't exactly an answer as it doesn't provide any solutions (yet!), but it's too big to fit on a comment...*

---

I did some testing (regarding file names) on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 and what I found out was that:

**1. PHP Can't Handle non-ASCII Filenames**

Although both Windows and Ubuntu can handle Unicode filenames (even RTL ones as it seems) PHP 5.3 requires hacks to deal even with the plain old ISO-8859-1, so it's better to keep it ASCII only for safety.

**2. The Lenght of the Filename Matters (Specially on Windows)**

On Ubuntu, the maximum length a filename can have (incluinding extension) is 255 (excluding path):

```
/var/www/uploads/123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345/
```

However, on Windows 7 (NTFS) the maximum lenght a filename can have depends on it's absolute path:

```
(0 + 0 + 244 + 11 chars) C:\1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234\1234567.txt
(0 + 3 + 240 + 11 chars) C:\123\123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\1234567.txt
(3 + 3 + 236 + 11 chars) C:\123\456\12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456\1234567.txt
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations) says that:

> NTFS allows **each** path component (directory or filename) to be 255
>   characters long.

**To the best of my knowledge (and testing), this is wrong.**

In total (counting slashes) all these examples have 259 chars, if you strip the `C:\` that gives 256 characters (not 255?!). The directories where created using the Explorer and you'll notice that it restrains itself from using all the available space for the directory name. The reason for this is to allow the creation of files using the [8.3 file naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). The same thing happens for other partitions.

Files don't need to reserve the 8.3 lenght requirements of course:

```
(255 chars) E:\12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901.txt
```

You can't create any more sub-directories if the absolute path of the parent directory has more than 242 characters, because `256 = 242 + 1 + \ + 8 + . + 3`. Using Windows Explorer, you can't create another directory if the parent directory has more than 233 characters (depending on the system locale), because `256 = 233 + 10 + \ + 8 + . + 3`; the `10` here is the length of the string `New folder`.

*Windows file system poses a nasty problem if you want to assure inter-operability between file systems.*

**3. Beware of Reserved Characters and Keywords**

Aside from removing *non-ASCII, non-printable and control characters*, you also need to re(place/move):

```
"*/:<>?\|
```

Just removing these characters might not be the best idea because the filename might lose some of it's meaning. I think that, at the very least, multiple occurences of these characters should be replaced by a single underscore (`_`), or perhaps something more representative (this is just an idea):

- **`"*?`** -> **`_`**
- **`/\|`** -> **`-`**
- **`:`** -> **`[ ]-[ ]`**
- **`<`** -> **`(`**
- **`>`** -> **`)`**

There are also [special keywords that should be avoided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) (like `NUL`), although I'm not sure how to overcome that. Perhaps a black list with a random name fallback would be a good approach to solve it.

**4. Case Sensitiveness**

This should go without saying, but if you want so ensure file uniqueness across different operating systems you should transform file names to a normalized case, that way `my_file.txt` and `My_File.txt` on Linux won't both become the same `my_file.txt` file on Windows.

**5. Make Sure It's Unique**

If the file name already exists, a [unique identifier should be appended](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/558431470922be267be2758051bb6ee4df8eb8fc/phunction/Disk.php#L508) to it's base file name.

Common unique identifiers include the UNIX timestamp, a digest of the file contents or a random string.

**6. Hidden Files**

Just because it can be named doesn't mean it should...

Dots are usually white-listed in file names but in Linux a hidden file is represented by a leading dot.

**7. Other Considerations**

If you have to strip some chars of the file name, the extension is usually more important than the base name of the file. Allowing a [considerable maximum number of characters for the file extension](http://alaeddin.tumblr.com/post/337616277/longest-file-extension-ever) (8-16) one should strip the characters from the base name. It's also important to note that in the unlikely event of having a more than one long extension - such as `_.graphmlz.tag.gz` - `_.graphmlz.tag` only `_` should be considered as the file base name in this case.

**8. Resources**

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) handles file name mangling pretty decently:

- [/src/calibre/utils/filenames.py](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kovid/calibre/trunk/view/head:/src/calibre/utils/filenames.py)
- [/src/calibre/library/save_to_disk.py](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kovid/calibre/trunk/view/head:/src/calibre/library/save_to_disk.py)

[Wikipedia page on file name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_mangling) and linked [chapter from Using Samba](http://oreilly.com/catalog/samba/chapter/book/ch05_04.html).

---

If for instance, you try to create a file that violates any of the rules 1/2/3, you'll get a very useful error:

```
Warning: touch(): Unable to create file ... because No error in ... on line ...
```

Answer (score 11):

I've always thought [Kohana did a pretty good job of it](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/url.php#L143).

```
public static function title($title, $separator = '-', $ascii_only = FALSE)
{
if ($ascii_only === TRUE)
{
// Transliterate non-ASCII characters
$title = UTF8::transliterate_to_ascii($title);

// Remove all characters that are not the separator, a-z, 0-9, or whitespace
$title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'a-z0-9\s]+!', '', strtolower($title));
}
else
{
// Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace
$title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', UTF8::strtolower($title));
}

// Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
$title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $title);

// Trim separators from the beginning and end
return trim($title, $separator);
}
```

The handy `UTF8::transliterate_to_ascii()` will turn stuff like ñ => n.

Of course, you could replace the other `UTF8::*` stuff with mb_* functions.

Answer (score 6):

I have adapted from another source and added a couple extra, maybe a little overkill

```
/**
 * Convert a string into a url safe address.
 *
 * @param string $unformatted
 * @return string
 */
public function formatURL($unformatted) {

    $url = strtolower(trim($unformatted));

    //replace accent characters, forien languages
    $search = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ'); 
    $replace = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o'); 
    $url = str_replace($search, $replace, $url);

    //replace common characters
    $search = array('&', '£', '$'); 
    $replace = array('and', 'pounds', 'dollars'); 
    $url= str_replace($search, $replace, $url);

    // remove - for spaces and union characters
    $find = array(' ', '&', '\r\n', '\n', '+', ',', '//');
    $url = str_replace($find, '-', $url);

    //delete and replace rest of special chars
    $find = array('/[^a-z0-9\-<>]/', '/[\-]+/', '/<[^>]*>/');
    $replace = array('', '-', '');
    $uri = preg_replace($find, $replace, $url);

    return $uri;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In terms of file uploads, you would be safest to prevent the user from controlling the file name.  As has already been hinted at, store the canonicalised filename in a database along with a randomly chosen and unique name which you'll use as the actual filename.

Using OWASP ESAPI, these names could be generated thus:

```
$userFilename   = ESAPI::getEncoder()->canonicalize($input_string);
$safeFilename   = ESAPI::getRandomizer()->getRandomFilename();
```

You could append a timestamp to the $safeFilename to help ensure that the randomly generated filename is unique without even checking for an existing file.

In terms of encoding for URL, and again using ESAPI:

```
$safeForURL     = ESAPI::getEncoder()->encodeForURL($input_string);
```

This method performs canonicalisation before encoding the string and will handle all character encodings.

Comment: Definitely - also, taking filename control away from users will prevent a possibility of 2 uploads having the same name.

Answer (score 5):

and this is Joomla 3.3.2 version from [`JFile::makeSafe($file)`](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFile.html#method_makeSafe)

```
public static function makeSafe($file)
{
    // Remove any trailing dots, as those aren't ever valid file names.
    $file = rtrim($file, '.');

    $regex = array('#(\.){2,}#', '#[^A-Za-z0-9\.\_\- ]#', '#^\.#');

    return trim(preg_replace($regex, '', $file));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend* [URLify for PHP (480+ stars on Github)](https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify) - "the PHP port of URLify.js from the Django project. Transliterates non-ascii characters for use in URLs".

Basic usage:

**To generate slugs for URLs:**

```
<?php

echo URLify::filter (' J\'étudie le français ');
// "jetudie-le-francais"

echo URLify::filter ('Lo siento, no hablo español.');
// "lo-siento-no-hablo-espanol"

?>
```

**To generate slugs for file names:**

```
<?php

echo URLify::filter ('фото.jpg', 60, "", true);
// "foto.jpg"

?>
```

*None of the other suggestions matched my criteria:

- Should be installable via composer
- Should not depend on iconv since it behaves differently on different systems
- Should be extendable to allow overrides and custom character replacements
- Popular (for instance many stars on Github)
- Has tests

As a bonus, URLify also removes certain words and strips away all characters not transliterated.

Here is a test case with tons of foreign characters being transliterated properly using URLify: https://gist.github.com/motin/a65e6c1cc303e46900d10894bf2da87f

Comment: Thanks - that looks ideal for my purposes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think having a list of chars to remove is safe. I would rather use the following:

For filenames: Use an internal ID or a hash of the filecontent. Save the document name in a database. This way you can keep the original filename and still find the file.

For url parameters: Use `urlencode()` to encode any special characters.

Comment: I agree, most of the methods listed here remove *known dangerous* characters - my method removes everything that isn't a known *safe* character. Since most systems slug encode post URL's I would suggest we continue to follow this proven method rather than using the documented **UTF-8 unsafe** urlencode().

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you will use it, you might want to add a length limit to protect against buffer overflows.

Comment: Yes, testing for mb_strlen() is always an important thing!

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice way to secure an upload filename:

```
$file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about this, for one `.\x00..\x20` can be reduced to `.\x00\x20`.

Comment: @Xeoncross: I think that `.\x00..\x20` removes dots and every character between `\x00` and `\x20`, whereas `.\x00\x20` should only remove those 3 bytes.

Comment: This answer requires more explaination for it to be safely used. Not much information about the exact syntax for charlist on the net.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's CodeIgniter's implementation.](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php)

```
/**
 * Sanitize Filename
 *
 * @param   string  $str        Input file name
 * @param   bool    $relative_path  Whether to preserve paths
 * @return  string
 */
public function sanitize_filename($str, $relative_path = FALSE)
{
    $bad = array(
        '../', '<!--', '-->', '<', '>',
        "'", '"', '&', '$', '#',
        '{', '}', '[', ']', '=',
        ';', '?', '%20', '%22',
        '%3c',      // <
        '%253c',    // <
        '%3e',      // >
        '%0e',      // >
        '%28',      // (
        '%29',      // )
        '%2528',    // (
        '%26',      // &
        '%24',      // $
        '%3f',      // ?
        '%3b',      // ;
        '%3d'       // =
    );

    if ( ! $relative_path)
    {
        $bad[] = './';
        $bad[] = '/';
    }

    $str = remove_invisible_characters($str, FALSE);
    return stripslashes(str_replace($bad, '', $str));
}
```

[And the `remove_invisible_characters` dependency.](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Common.php)

```
function remove_invisible_characters($str, $url_encoded = TRUE)
{
    $non_displayables = array();

    // every control character except newline (dec 10),
    // carriage return (dec 13) and horizontal tab (dec 09)
    if ($url_encoded)
    {
        $non_displayables[] = '/%0[0-8bcef]/';  // url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
        $non_displayables[] = '/%1[0-9a-f]/';   // url encoded 16-31
    }

    $non_displayables[] = '/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+/S';   // 00-08, 11, 12, 14-31, 127

    do
    {
        $str = preg_replace($non_displayables, '', $str, -1, $count);
    }
    while ($count);

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have entry titles with all kinds of weird latin characters as well as some HTML tags that I needed to translate into a useful dash-delimited filename format. I combined @SoLoGHoST's answer with a couple of items from @Xeoncross's answer and customized a bit.

```
    function sanitize($string,$force_lowercase=true) {
    //Clean up titles for filenames
    $clean = strip_tags($string);
    $clean = strtr($clean, array('Š' => 'S','Ž' => 'Z','š' => 's','ž' => 'z','Ÿ' => 'Y','À' => 'A','Á' => 'A','Â' => 'A','Ã' => 'A','Ä' => 'A','Å' => 'A','Ç' => 'C','È' => 'E','É' => 'E','Ê' => 'E','Ë' => 'E','Ì' => 'I','Í' => 'I','Î' => 'I','Ï' => 'I','Ñ' => 'N','Ò' => 'O','Ó' => 'O','Ô' => 'O','Õ' => 'O','Ö' => 'O','Ø' => 'O','Ù' => 'U','Ú' => 'U','Û' => 'U','Ü' => 'U','Ý' => 'Y','à' => 'a','á' => 'a','â' => 'a','ã' => 'a','ä' => 'a','å' => 'a','ç' => 'c','è' => 'e','é' => 'e','ê' => 'e','ë' => 'e','ì' => 'i','í' => 'i','î' => 'i','ï' => 'i','ñ' => 'n','ò' => 'o','ó' => 'o','ô' => 'o','õ' => 'o','ö' => 'o','ø' => 'o','ù' => 'u','ú' => 'u','û' => 'u','ü' => 'u','ý' => 'y','ÿ' => 'y'));
    $clean = strtr($clean, array('Þ' => 'TH', 'þ' => 'th', 'Ð' => 'DH', 'ð' => 'dh', 'ß' => 'ss', 'Œ' => 'OE', 'œ' => 'oe', 'Æ' => 'AE', 'æ' => 'ae', 'µ' => 'u','—' => '-'));
    $clean = str_replace("--", "-", preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9-]/i", "", preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/[^\w-\.\-]/'), array('-', ''), $clean)));

    return ($force_lowercase) ?
        (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) ?
            mb_strtolower($clean, 'UTF-8') :
            strtolower($clean) :
        $clean;
}
```

I needed to manually add the em dash character (—) to the translation array. There may be others but so far my file names are looking good.

So:

**Part 1: My dad’s “Žurburts”?—they’re (not) the best!**

becomes:

**part-1-my-dads-zurburts-theyre-not-the-best**

I just add ".html" to the returned string.

Comment: Still missing some Czech and Slovak characters: `'ľ' => 'l', 'Ľ' => 'L', 'č' => 'c', 'Č' => 'C', 'ť' => 't', 'Ť' => 'T', 'ň' => 'n', 'Ň' => 'N', 'ĺ' => 'l', 'Ĺ' => 'L', 'Ř' => 'R', 'ř' => 'r', 'ě' => 'e', 'Ě' => 'E', 'ů' => 'u', 'Ů' => 'U'`

Comment: And no doubt many more. I'm actually trying to figure out if there exists an ISO- set that includes combinations of characters. How does one "choose" one set if the content demands characters from all of them? UTF-8 I'm assuming...

Comment: I found out [how to transliterate any string using one line of PHP](http://www.jasom.net/php-prepare-sanitize-transliterate-convert-change-user-string-input-for-filename-or-url-address): `$string = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin;Latin-ASCII;', $string);` See my answer below or read linked blog post.

Comment: IF you're using Drupal and IF you install an extension. Not really "one line of PHP".

Comment: No, you have read it wrong: **IF you can install PHP extensions on your server (or hosting)** :-) Here's [the post](http://www.jasom.net/php-prepare-sanitize-transliterate-convert-change-user-string-input-for-filename-or-url-address).

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks @JasomDotnet --I have my current solution working for now but it's a limited character set so the extension is worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

why not simply use php's [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode)? it replaces "dangerous" characters with their hex representation for urls (i.e. `%20` for a space)

Comment: The % character is not recommended for filenames and hex encoded characters do not look as nice in the URL. Browsers can support UTF-8 strings which are much nicer and easier for non-ascii languages.

Comment: you could do a urlencode and THEN a str_replace('%20','-',url) ?

Answer (score 2):

There are already several solutions provided for this question but I have read and tested most of the code here and I ended up with this solution which is a mix of what I learned here:

### The function

The function is bundled here in a **Symfony2** bundle but it can be extracted to be used as **plain PHP**, it only has a dependency with the `iconv` function that must be enabled:

**Filesystem.php**:

```
<?php

namespace COil\Bundle\COilCoreBundle\Component\HttpKernel\Util;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Util\Filesystem as BaseFilesystem;

/**
 * Extends the Symfony filesystem object.
 */
class Filesystem extends BaseFilesystem
{
    /**
     * Make a filename safe to use in any function. (Accents, spaces, special chars...)
     * The iconv function must be activated.
     *
     * @param string  $fileName       The filename to sanitize (with or without extension)
     * @param string  $defaultIfEmpty The default string returned for a non valid filename (only special chars or separators)
     * @param string  $separator      The default separator
     * @param boolean $lowerCase      Tells if the string must converted to lower case
     *
     * @author COil <https://github.com/COil>
     * @see    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668854/sanitizing-strings-to-make-them-url-and-filename-safe
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function sanitizeFilename($fileName, $defaultIfEmpty = 'default', $separator = '_', $lowerCase = true)
    {
    // Gather file informations and store its extension
    $fileInfos = pathinfo($fileName);
    $fileExt   = array_key_exists('extension', $fileInfos) ? '.'. strtolower($fileInfos['extension']) : '';

    // Removes accents
    $fileName = @iconv('UTF-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $fileInfos['filename']);

    // Removes all characters that are not separators, letters, numbers, dots or whitespaces
    $fileName = preg_replace("/[^ a-zA-Z". preg_quote($separator). "\d\.\s]/", '', $lowerCase ? strtolower($fileName) : $fileName);

    // Replaces all successive separators into a single one
    $fileName = preg_replace('!['. preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $fileName);

    // Trim beginning and ending seperators
    $fileName = trim($fileName, $separator);

    // If empty use the default string
    if (empty($fileName)) {
        $fileName = $defaultIfEmpty;
    }

    return $fileName. $fileExt;
    }
}
```

### The unit tests

What is interesting is that I have created PHPUnit tests, first to test edge cases and so you can check if it fits your needs:
(If you find a bug, feel free to add a test case)

**FilesystemTest.php**:

```
<?php

namespace COil\Bundle\COilCoreBundle\Tests\Unit\Helper;

use COil\Bundle\COilCoreBundle\Component\HttpKernel\Util\Filesystem;

/**
 * Test the Filesystem custom class.
 */
class FilesystemTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * test sanitizeFilename()
     */
    public function testFilesystem()
    {
    $fs = new Filesystem();

    $this->assertEquals('logo_orange.gif', $fs->sanitizeFilename('--logö  _  __   ___   ora@@ñ--~gé--.gif'), '::sanitizeFilename() handles complex filename with specials chars');
    $this->assertEquals('coilstack', $fs->sanitizeFilename('cOiLsTaCk'), '::sanitizeFilename() converts all characters to lower case');
    $this->assertEquals('cOiLsTaCk', $fs->sanitizeFilename('cOiLsTaCk', 'default', '_', false), '::sanitizeFilename() lower case can be desactivated, passing false as the 4th argument');
    $this->assertEquals('coil_stack', $fs->sanitizeFilename('coil stack'), '::sanitizeFilename() convert a white space to a separator');
    $this->assertEquals('coil-stack', $fs->sanitizeFilename('coil stack', 'default', '-'), '::sanitizeFilename() can use a different separator as the 3rd argument');
    $this->assertEquals('coil_stack', $fs->sanitizeFilename('coil          stack'), '::sanitizeFilename() removes successive white spaces to a single separator');
    $this->assertEquals('coil_stack', $fs->sanitizeFilename('       coil stack'), '::sanitizeFilename() removes spaces at the beginning of the string');
    $this->assertEquals('coil_stack', $fs->sanitizeFilename('coil   stack         '), '::sanitizeFilename() removes spaces at the end of the string');
    $this->assertEquals('coilstack', $fs->sanitizeFilename('coil,,,,,,stack'), '::sanitizeFilename() removes non-ASCII characters');
    $this->assertEquals('coil_stack', $fs->sanitizeFilename('coil_stack  '), '::sanitizeFilename() keeps separators');
    $this->assertEquals('coil_stack', $fs->sanitizeFilename(' coil________stack'), '::sanitizeFilename() converts successive separators into a single one');
    $this->assertEquals('coil_stack.gif', $fs->sanitizeFilename('cOil Stack.GiF'), '::sanitizeFilename() lower case filename and extension');
    $this->assertEquals('copy_of_coil.stack.exe', $fs->sanitizeFilename('Copy of coil.stack.exe'), '::sanitizeFilename() keeps dots before the extension');
    $this->assertEquals('default.doc', $fs->sanitizeFilename('____________.doc'), '::sanitizeFilename() returns a default file name if filename only contains special chars');
    $this->assertEquals('default.docx', $fs->sanitizeFilename('     ___ -  --_     __%%%%__¨¨¨***____      .docx'), '::sanitizeFilename() returns a default file name if filename only contains special chars');
    $this->assertEquals('logo_edition_1314352521.jpg', $fs->sanitizeFilename('logo_edition_1314352521.jpg'), '::sanitizeFilename() returns the filename untouched if it does not need to be modified');
    $userId = rand(1, 10);
    $this->assertEquals('user_doc_'. $userId. '.doc', $fs->sanitizeFilename('亐亐亐亐亐.doc', 'user_doc_'. $userId), '::sanitizeFilename() returns the default string (the 2nd argument) if it can\'t be sanitized');
    }
}
```

The test results: (checked on **Ubuntu** with PHP 5.3.2 and **MacOsX** with PHP 5.3.17:

```
All tests pass:

phpunit -c app/ src/COil/Bundle/COilCoreBundle/Tests/Unit/Helper/FilesystemTest.php
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/strangebuzz.com/app/phpunit.xml.dist

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.75Mb

OK (1 test, 17 assertions)
```

Comment: This assumes mostly Latin based input. Add more UTF-8 characters from other languages to see where you will have problems.

Comment: @Xeoncross I agree, as Christian said one must save an Id or hash AND the original filename. But this function provides an alternative as you can specify a default string when the sanitize process fails. I have added an unit test for this case. Thanks for reporting the bug.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution #1: You have ability to install PHP extensions on server (hosting)

For transliteration of "almost every single language on the planet Earth" to ASCII characters.

1. Install [PHP Intl](http://php.net/manual/intl.setup.php) extension first. This is command for Debian (Ubuntu): `sudo aptitude install php5-intl`
2. This is my fileName function (create test.php and paste there following code):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

function pr($string) {
  print '<hr>';
  print '"' . fileName($string) . '"';
  print '<br>';
  print '"' . $string . '"';
}

function fileName($string) {
  // remove html tags
  $clean = strip_tags($string);
  // transliterate
  $clean = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin;Latin-ASCII;', $clean);
  // remove non-number and non-letter characters
  $clean = str_replace('--', '-', preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-\_]/i', '', preg_replace(array(
    '/\s/', 
    '/[^\w-\.\-]/'
  ), array(
    '_', 
    ''
  ), $clean)));
  // replace '-' for '_'
  $clean = strtr($clean, array(
    '-' => '_'
  ));
  // remove double '__'
  $positionInString = stripos($clean, '__');
  while ($positionInString !== false) {
    $clean = str_replace('__', '_', $clean);
    $positionInString = stripos($clean, '__');
  }
  // remove '_' from the end and beginning of the string
  $clean = rtrim(ltrim($clean, '_'), '_');
  // lowercase the string
  return strtolower($clean);
}
pr('_replace(\'~&([a-z]{1,2})(ac134/56f4315981743 8765475[]lt7ňl2ú5äňú138yé73ťž7ýľute|');
pr(htmlspecialchars('<script>alert(\'hacked\')</script>'));
pr('Álix----_Ãxel!?!?');
pr('áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ');
pr('üÿÄËÏÖÜ.ŸåÅ');
pr('nie4č a a§ôňäääaš');
pr('Мао Цзэдун');
pr('毛泽东');
pr('ماو تسي تونغ');
pr('مائو تسه‌تونگ');
pr('מאו דזה-דונג');
pr('მაო ძედუნი');
pr('Mao Trạch Đông');
pr('毛澤東');
pr('เหมา เจ๋อตง');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This line is core:

```
  // transliterate
  $clean = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin;Latin-ASCII;', $clean);
```

Answer based on [this post](http://www.jasom.net/php-prepare-sanitize-transliterate-convert-change-user-string-input-for-filename-or-url-address).

#### Solution #2: You don't have ability to install PHP extensions on server (hosting)

[image]

Pretty good job is done in [transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module for CMS Drupal. It supports almost every single language on the planet Earth. I suggest to check plugin [repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/transliteration/tree/?h=7.x-3.2) if you want to have really complete solution sanitizing strings.

Answer (score 1):

This post seems to work the best among all that I have tied. http://gsynuh.com/php-string-filename-url-safe/205

Comment: That post is very short-sighed and assumes everything is english.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code used by Prestashop to sanitize urls :

```
replaceAccentedChars
```

is used by

```
str2url
```

to remove diacritics

```
function replaceAccentedChars($str)
{
    $patterns = array(
        /* Lowercase */
        '/[\x{0105}\x{00E0}\x{00E1}\x{00E2}\x{00E3}\x{00E4}\x{00E5}]/u',
        '/[\x{00E7}\x{010D}\x{0107}]/u',
        '/[\x{010F}]/u',
        '/[\x{00E8}\x{00E9}\x{00EA}\x{00EB}\x{011B}\x{0119}]/u',
        '/[\x{00EC}\x{00ED}\x{00EE}\x{00EF}]/u',
        '/[\x{0142}\x{013E}\x{013A}]/u',
        '/[\x{00F1}\x{0148}]/u',
        '/[\x{00F2}\x{00F3}\x{00F4}\x{00F5}\x{00F6}\x{00F8}]/u',
        '/[\x{0159}\x{0155}]/u',
        '/[\x{015B}\x{0161}]/u',
        '/[\x{00DF}]/u',
        '/[\x{0165}]/u',
        '/[\x{00F9}\x{00FA}\x{00FB}\x{00FC}\x{016F}]/u',
        '/[\x{00FD}\x{00FF}]/u',
        '/[\x{017C}\x{017A}\x{017E}]/u',
        '/[\x{00E6}]/u',
        '/[\x{0153}]/u',

        /* Uppercase */
        '/[\x{0104}\x{00C0}\x{00C1}\x{00C2}\x{00C3}\x{00C4}\x{00C5}]/u',
        '/[\x{00C7}\x{010C}\x{0106}]/u',
        '/[\x{010E}]/u',
        '/[\x{00C8}\x{00C9}\x{00CA}\x{00CB}\x{011A}\x{0118}]/u',
        '/[\x{0141}\x{013D}\x{0139}]/u',
        '/[\x{00D1}\x{0147}]/u',
        '/[\x{00D3}]/u',
        '/[\x{0158}\x{0154}]/u',
        '/[\x{015A}\x{0160}]/u',
        '/[\x{0164}]/u',
        '/[\x{00D9}\x{00DA}\x{00DB}\x{00DC}\x{016E}]/u',
        '/[\x{017B}\x{0179}\x{017D}]/u',
        '/[\x{00C6}]/u',
        '/[\x{0152}]/u');

    $replacements = array(
            'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 'ss', 't', 'u', 'y', 'z', 'ae', 'oe',
            'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'L', 'N', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'Z', 'AE', 'OE'
        );

    return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
}

function str2url($str)
{
    if (function_exists('mb_strtolower'))
        $str = mb_strtolower($str, 'utf-8');

    $str = trim($str);
    if (!function_exists('mb_strtolower'))
        $str = replaceAccentedChars($str);

    // Remove all non-whitelist chars.
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\'\:\/\[\]-\pL]/u', '', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[\s\'\:\/\[\]-]+/', ' ', $str);
    $str = str_replace(array(' ', '/'), '-', $str);

    // If it was not possible to lowercase the string with mb_strtolower, we do it after the transformations.
    // This way we lose fewer special chars.
    if (!function_exists('mb_strtolower'))
        $str = strtolower($str);

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good function:

```
public function getFriendlyURL($string) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF8');
    $string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~[^\-\pL\pN\s]+~u', '-', $string);
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
    $string = trim($string, "-");
    $string = strtolower($string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: This looks bad. `\\s+` means a backslash followed by one or more whitespace. What is that about? Also, this uses blacklisting rather than whitelisting ignoring things like `CMD`, null, or `BEL`.

Comment: Still bad. Now strings like `/blog/2014-02/just-in-time` are not allowed. Please use the tested code above or use the `phunction` PHP framework code.

Comment: That's right. This function is only for the "just-in-time" part. Could be useful for some people.

Comment: You can change the regex `preg_replace('~[^\-\pL\pN\s]+~u', '-', $string)`

Comment: Awesome! I added also: string = trim($string, "-");

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 good answers to slugfy your data, use it https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987966/971619 or it https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610586/971619

Answer (score -4):

```
// CLEAN ILLEGAL CHARACTERS
function clean_filename($source_file)
{
    $search[] = " ";
    $search[] = "&";
    $search[] = "$";
    $search[] = ",";
    $search[] = "!";
    $search[] = "@";
    $search[] = "#";
    $search[] = "^";
    $search[] = "(";
    $search[] = ")";
    $search[] = "+";
    $search[] = "=";
    $search[] = "[";
    $search[] = "]";

    $replace[] = "_";
    $replace[] = "and";
    $replace[] = "S";
    $replace[] = "_";
    $replace[] = "";
    $replace[] = "";
    $replace[] = "";
    $replace[] = "";
    $replace[] = "";
    $replace[] = "";
    $replace[] = "";
    $replace[] = "";
    $replace[] = "";
    $replace[] = "";

    return str_replace($search,$replace,$source_file);

}
```