# ignore '&' in var contents passed in address bar

Tags: php

i have a download.php file which gets and opens files. i have a problem is that files were named using '&' in the file name so i get file not found when trying to access files with '&' in them.

example: download.phpf=one_&_another.pdf

in the download.php file i use get to the the file name ($_GET['f']) the example above throws the error file not found if i change the file name to one_and_another.pdf it works.

Yes renaming would be nice if there wasnt a whole lot of these files named this way.

I need to know how to ignore the fact that '&' doesnt mean im about to pass another var in php.

Comment: @user535617: Won't work, it's not an HTML encoding issue but a URL encoding issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you can control the query strings, you need to URL encode the ampersands so they look like this:

```
download.php?f=one_%26_another.pdf
```

Then look for `$_GET['f']` as usual. Otherwise a literal ampersand `&` would break `$_GET` into

```
{ 'f' => 'one_', '_another.pdf' => '' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably just need to `urlencode()` the `&` properly in your links:

```
download.php?f=one_%26_another.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule number 1 for accepting user input: do not trust it.

[Refer to this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668854/php-sanitizing-strings-to-make-them-url-and-filename-safe) for your solution.

Comment: Good advice and link, but he is not *trusting* the file name in question as such. He just has an encoding problem. Still, renaming them according to a better scheme is a option worth considering