# Filtering URLS for output PHP

Tags: php, security

I'd like to make sure URLs such as
`javascript:alert('a');`
and vbscript varients etc. are not allowed by whitelisting `https?|ftp
That's easy enough: ^(?:https?|ftp)://`
But how can I allow relative urls as well?
such as ../../../blah and ./blah also /images/img.png

In other words is using `^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://|[./])` safe?

I've asked around and a possible solution might be:
parse_url

if !scheme or scheme == http or scheme == https or scheme == ftp or scheme == mailto

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, what are you trying to protect against?

Comment: XSS, I'm trying to filter URLs such to go into <a href="" or <img src=""

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regular expressions you could use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and check that *scheme* is either empty or one of `http`, `https`, and `ftp`:

```
$components = parse_url($url);
if (!isset($url['scheme']) || in_array(strtolower($url['scheme']), array('http', 'https', 'ftp'))) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

Comment: Yep I added that to my question 5 mins ago. :)

Comment: @John: I hadn’t noticed that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also see: [Sanitizing strings to make them URL and filename safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668854/php-sanitizing-strings-to-make-them-url-and-filename-safe)

> I'm trying to filter URLs such to go
> into `<a href=""` or `<img src=""`

Be careful, because it's possible to "break out" of the attribute with just a "starts with" regular expression. For instance, I could provide `http://safeurl.com" onclick="alert('xss attack')`, and when inserted into your attribute you would have:

```
<a href="http://safeurl.com" onclick="alert('xss attack')">
```

Make sure to [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the value as well as any other security you're doing.

I would probably consider against allowing `../../relative/urls` or perhaps using parse_url as [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856006/filtering-urls-for-output-php/5856152#5856152) has suggested.

Check out the info on [OWASP.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5#How_to_Protect_Against_It_2) for some more advice.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to use hrtmlentities to properly escape the data before putting it in the attributes. I'm not sure urlencode() should be used?

Comment: I would use urlencode() on each slashed segment to be safe. This is definitely worth writing a function for, something really solid and paranoid.