# mkdir utf-8 Cyrillic

Tags: php, utf-8, mkdir

I need to create directories in utf-8 Cyrillic. i use `mkdir` function for this, then i try to do:

```
$img_dir = './img/product/'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
if(!is_dir($img_dir)){
  mkdir($img_dir, 0700);
};
```

in `$_POST['title']` i have titles of product something like that : "Кеды", "Макасины" but this function create folders with such names: "РљРµРґС‹","РњР°РєР°СЃРёРЅС‹".

This is associated with the coding of my OS? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do with `htmlspecialchars` but if you want to sanitize filenames, this might be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668854/sanitizing-strings-to-make-them-url-and-filename-safe What kind of OS and what file system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `htmlspecialchars` you need to use `htmlentities`, which includes the whole cyrillic alphabet.

```
$img_dir = './img/product/'.htmlentities($_POST['title']);
if(!is_dir($img_dir)){
mkdir($img_dir, 0700);
};
```

Comment: TIP: Do not forget to add this in your database with this html-filename too