# How to know if a file name is valid on the current platform?

Tags: php, filesystems

All platforms (and probably filesystems) have different rules regarding which characters are allowed as a file or directory name. Furthermore, some systems have a blacklist of filenames: for example on Windows, `com1` is an invalid file name.

**Is there a way to know programmatically the rules to compute a valid file name in PHP?**

As an alternative, is there a trustable list of *safe* characters that are guaranteed to be valid on any system, apart from `[0-9a-zA-Z]`?

Please note that a solution based on *try to save, if it fails, the filename is invalid* is not acceptable for my use case.

Comment: Common sense is the best general guidance; you should have complete control over the filenames you use

Comment: @Mark I precisely don't, this is to implement a key-value pair storage,  and I need to know whether I should encode the file name and when I can just leave it as is (helps readability).

Comment: Just a thought, but allowing mixed case filenames may not be wise. (On file systems which are case insensitive this could result in a clash.)

Comment: uses a md5 hash for the file name like php does for sessions

Comment: @Dagon I've considered this option, but I would have been happy to use the actual key whenever possible as the file name, to help readability if debugging is needed (locating a file by hand). Also, middaparka's comment applies in case of a MD5 hash.

Comment: what case are your md5 hashes?

Comment: @Dagon Just realized my mistake, a hex-encoded MD5 hash is obviously not mixed case, so no risk here. Your solution is fine, apart from the readability issue.

Comment: If you can use something like memcached or redis, that's typically better for key/value storage than the filesystem

Comment: @Mark This is a generic library, I'm implementing a filesystem version, a database version, and a Memcached version (which has its own drawbacks, in particular the non-guarantee of the data persistence)!

Comment: Understood, and I can appreciate the problems: fortunately I can use a hashed code for my keys, and don't need to worry about persistence

Answer (score 2):

Already answered well, [Sanitizing strings to make them URL and filename safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2668953/288513)

> I found this larger function in the [Chyrp](http://chyrp.net) code:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Function: sanitize
>  * Returns a sanitized string, typically for URLs.
>  *
>  * Parameters:
>  *     $string - The string to sanitize.
>  *     $force_lowercase - Force the string to lowercase?
>  *     $anal - If set to *true*, will remove all non-alphanumeric characters.
>  */
> function sanitize($string, $force_lowercase = true, $anal = false) {
>     $strip = array("~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "=", "+", "[", "{", "]",
>                    "}", "\\", "|", ";", ":", "\"", "'", "&#8216;", "&#8217;", "&#8220;", "&#8221;", "&#8211;", "&#8212;",
>                    "â€”", "â€“", ",", "<", ".", ">", "/", "?");
>     $clean = trim(str_replace($strip, "", strip_tags($string)));
>     $clean = preg_replace('/\s+/', "-", $clean);
>     $clean = ($anal) ? preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $clean) : $clean ;
>     return ($force_lowercase) ?
>         (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) ?
>             mb_strtolower($clean, 'UTF-8') :
>             strtolower($clean) :
>         $clean;
> }
> ```
>
> and this one in the [wordpress](http://wordpress.org) code
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Sanitizes a filename replacing whitespace with dashes
>  *
>  * Removes special characters that are illegal in filenames on certain
>  * operating systems and special characters requiring special escaping
>  * to manipulate at the command line. Replaces spaces and consecutive
>  * dashes with a single dash. Trim period, dash and underscore from beginning
>  * and end of filename.
>  *
>  * @since 2.1.0
>  *
>  * @param string $filename The filename to be sanitized
>  * @return string The sanitized filename
>  */
> function sanitize_file_name( $filename ) {
>   $filename_raw = $filename;
>   $special_chars = array("?", "[", "]", "/", "\\", "=", "<", ">", ":", ";", ",", "'", "\"", "&", "$", "#", "*", "(", ")", "|", "~", "`",
>   "!", "{", "}");
>   $special_chars = apply_filters('sanitize_file_name_chars', $special_chars, $filename_raw);
>   $filename = str_replace($special_chars, '', $filename);
>   $filename = preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', $filename);
>   $filename = trim($filename, '.-_');
>   return apply_filters('sanitize_file_name', $filename, $filename_raw);
> }
> ```
>
> ### Update Sept 2012
>
> [Alix Axel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89771/alix-axel) has done
>   some incredible work in this area. His phunction framework includes
>   several great text filters and transformations.
>
> - [Unaccent](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction/Text.php#L297)
> - [Slug](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction/Text.php#L249)
> - [Filter](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction.php#L301)