# Strip ending slashes from a url

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a url safe for later use.
So I want to strip the slashes from the end of the url string.

Actually I'm doing:

```
function getUrl() {
    $url = "url/with/ending/slashes///";
    if(..someConditions..) {
        $url = false;
    }
    return $url
}

$a = getUrl();

while($a !== $a = rtrim($a, '/'));
```

So the string can have a string value or a boolean value

There will be any unexpected result or downside when dealing with unexpected values of the string? (like specific strings, booleans values, integers, etc.?)

Comment: You should take a look at: 

[Sanitizing strings to make them URL and filename safe][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668854/sanitizing-strings-to-make-them-url-and-filename-safe

Comment: I would also add that I found the *rtrim/ltrim* functions to already strip multiple slashes. So my function is not really needed. Is not written into the documentation, but a test can easily show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if result is not false before moving forward,

```
$a = getUrl();
if($a){
   while($a !== $a = rtrim($a, '/'));
}
```