# Php Folder name with special characters inside

Tags: php

I have website where I create a file from a form. The user have to write a comapany  name and it will create a folder with the company name and save the company name inside my Database, later when some steps are made on my website here is an exemple how I create a folder :

```
$folder_name = format_folder_name($entreprise->getNom());
$path_file = $path_upload . '/' . $folder_name;
createFolderIfNotExist($path_file);
```

Recently I had a case where the company is "LALAL & OMOMO" (fake name of course ^^)
One folder I've been created correctly but for some reasons it can't work correctly because of the "&" inside the company name. When I want to reuse the folder inside my code it can't find id beacause of what is after the "&" and it is consider as a diffrent command.

how could I save and create folders correctly with the & inside my folder name ? (I don't want to change company name).

here is an exemple from when i want to upload the company logo :

```php
// create folder company name if not exist
$entreprise_folder_name = format_folder_name($_POST["create_entreprise_nom"]);
$path_file = $path_upload . '/' . $entreprise_folder_name;
createFolderIfNotExist($path_file);
// create folder "Logo" if not exist
$path_file .= "/Logo";
createFolderIfNotExist($path_file);
```

And when I take a look to the folder I have to folder with my company name

- LALAL_&_OMOMO
- LALAL__OMOMO

The logo is saved in the second folder

I'm affraid to have the same case with some others caracters like " ' " for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668854/sanitizing-strings-to-make-them-url-and-filename-safe

Comment: WHat OS are you using I can create directories with that name on Windows and Ubuntu? ... thats all I have access to now

Comment: The os is Debian, I canc reate folder with "&" correct but later with my code when it needs to go inside this folder I can't beaucause what is wrote after the "&" is consider as a different command

Comment: Wrap dir name in quotes

Comment: _“but later with my code when it needs to go inside this folder I can't because what is wrote after the "&" is consider as a different command”_ - please show what you are actually doing at that point.

Comment: I've edited my question with an exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `regex` to replace the `invalid folder name` with `normal characters`.

```
$path_file = $path_upload . '/' . preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\_\-\.]/i", '', $folder_name);
```

[Regex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)