# Are Latin encoded characters considered URL safe?

Tags: url, friendly-url

Are Latin encoded characters considered URL safe?

Having read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695438/safe-characters-for-friendly-url), I'm aware that web safe characters are outlined in [this document](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). The specs do not make clear, however, if Latin encoded characters are part of the unreserved list. For example: `ç` and `õ`.

I don't see why those characters would not be included in the unreserved list. But, that said, I'm yet to see any URLs that contain such characters.

**Relevant question**: Assuming I can use such characters in my URL, should I?

My URLs will be generated by user input. Should I keep titles with such characters, or substitute them? For example, `ç` to becomes `c`, and so on.

My reader's native language is Portuguese, but I'm not sure if they will care about these characters in the page's friendly-URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RFC you linked mentioned specifically mentions ASCII as the character set for URIs:

> The ABNF notation defines its terminal values to be non-negative
> integers (codepoints) based on the US-ASCII coded character set
> [ASCII].

That would make characters outside of ASCII not safe, as far as the RFC is concerned.

Of course, this is all before [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) existed. There is an [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3490) that specifies how  conversions between ASCII and Unicode on the URL should occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any characters you want, because if any character is used outside the range of ASCII code list the percent-code octets is used in order to make the uri transportable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).