# Can hyphens be used in query string values?

Tags: php, http, encoding, query-string

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695438/safe-characters-for-friendly-url). except that my question is more sepcific as it is about whether a hyphen can be used in a query string parameter value.

I am parsing `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` with PHP. I would like to know whether it is syntactically correct to use hyphens in query string values such as in the following case, or whether hyphens must be escaped in the browser URL. What about underscores?

```
http://example.com/?q1=query-string-value-one&q2=query-string-value-two
```

According to [this document](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201008/what_characters_are_allowed_unencoded_in_query_strings/) hyphens should be OK in all standards-compliant browsers, but I wanted to double check.

Thanks.

Comment: [Well, have you given a try to see if it works?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289336/is-it-okay-to-downvote-questions-asking-if-some-code-could-work-but-not-actually)

Comment: Well, I don't just want to know if it works. I need to know whether it is legal according to RFC specs.

Comment: yes `hyphens` can be used . only characters can reliably use for the actual name parts of a URL are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, ., _, and ~.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safe characters for friendly url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695438/safe-characters-for-friendly-url)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate @HansZ. The question you link to is concerned about legal characters in a url _in general_. This question is concerned with how query parameter _names_ are parsed.

Comment: Just in values, or can they be used in keys as well?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are talking about query string parameters which must be encoded using [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function:

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a
>   query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next
>   page.

According to the documentation `-` does not require encoding.

Answer (score 17):

**Yes**

Hyphens can be used for query string parameter names

Answer (score 1):

This is official docs https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.3

> Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
> purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase
> letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.
>
> ```
>   unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> ```