# Is this a valid URL query string?

Tags: string, url

My question below is:

Is this a valid URL?

http://www.exmple.org/News:98654357,C:1234567890

My questions is basically
are ":" and "," ok in "News:98654357,C:1234567890" for the query string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters make a URL invalid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safe characters for friendly url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695438/safe-characters-for-friendly-url)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ":" and "," are valid characters in a URL.