# Requests with URL parameters

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest

In an HTTP get request like this,

`http://example.com/page?parameter=value&also=another`

i can get the pages with parameter=value and alse=another,
But I want something like,

```
http://example.com/page?parameter<value&also=another
```

So that i can get the pages with their parameters are less then value.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works for you.

```
http://example.com/page?parameter={"lt":value}&also=another
```

Pass JSON object in query.

Answer (score 0):

That `<` character is not allowed in the URL.

You may check out this [questin and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695438/safe-characters-for-friendly-url).