# what is the difference between encodeURI and decodeUri

Tags: javascript

I want to url encode a string in javascript:

but these 2 function calls give the same result:

```
encodeURI('g0sceq3EkiAQTvyaZ07C+C4SZQz9FaGTV4Zwq4HkAnc=') === decodeURI('g0sceq3EkiAQTvyaZ07C+C4SZQz9FaGTV4Zwq4HkAnc=');  // true
```

both return `g0sceq3EkiAQTvyaZ07C+C4SZQz9FaGTV4Zwq4HkAnc=`.

Should the `+` sign and `=` sign not be encoded?

I thought `=` would be `%3D` and `+` would be `%2B`?

Comment: `encodeURI` doesn't encode all characters, just ones "unsafe" for URIs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description

Comment: how can I encode all characters

Comment: `encodeURI()` encodes special characters, except: `, / ? : @ & = + $ # `
.(Use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode these characters). ref:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: @dagda1 Why would you _want_ to encode all characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent`. Note, neither function is idempotent; If you accidentally double-encode a component, you will have to double-decode it -

```js
console.log
  ( encodeURIComponent ("=")     // %3D
  , decodeURIComponent ("%3D")   // =

  , encodeURIComponent ("%3D")   // %253D
  , decodeURIComponent ("%253D") // %3D

  , encodeURIComponent (encodeURIComponent ("="))     // %253D
  , decodeURIComponent (decodeURIComponent ("%253D")) // =
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer does not answer your question.

The answer is: you think `+` should be encoded but it is a safe URI character. See [Safe characters for friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695438/safe-characters-for-friendly-url)

```
const a = encodeURI("a%")
const b = decodeURI("a")

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(a === b) /// false
```

Comment: Well, `+` is safe, but `+` is interpreted as a space, not as a plus sign if you don't encode it in the query string.