# Broken image on Next JS

Tags: next.js, photo

here is my code snippet and I included a photo showing the browser.

`<div className='flex justify-between items-center w-full h-full px-2 2xl:px-16'> <Image src='/public/assets/BL Logo (1).png' alt='/' width={125} height={50}/> </div>`

I tried changing files but I get the same result. I am trying to get this photo to cooperate and load upon the local browser. I know I am close but not sure what else to do at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `/public` from the path.

I haven't used Next in a long while, but you may also need to make your file name [url-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695438/what-are-the-safe-characters-for-making-urls/695450#695450) (remove the spaces and parentheses — or `encodeURIComponent`.