# How do I sanitize title URIs with PHP?

Tags: php, rest, uri, sanitization

I am programming a blog and I want the URIs to be the title like the question title here in stackoverflow or like wordpress.
What are the rules for sanitizing a URI?
Is there an already made code in PHP that does this?

Thanks in advance,
Omer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many CMS's have implemented something like that, [the one of Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url/25537#25537) has been posted in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url). You might be interested in the [question about this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522466/what-makes-a-friendly-url) in general, too.

Answer (score 6):

This might be the shortest way to replace any non alphanumeric character with a single hyphen:

```
trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', strtolower($str)), '-')
```

Answer (score 6):

[Here's how drupal does it](http://drupal.org/node/63924).

In case of site goes down:

```
<?php
function pathauto_cleanstring($string)
{
    $url = $string;
    $url = preg_replace('~[^\\pL0-9_]+~u', '-', $url); // substitutes anything but letters, numbers and '_' with separator
    $url = trim($url, "-");
    $url = iconv("utf-8", "us-ascii//TRANSLIT", $url); // TRANSLIT does the whole job
    $url = strtolower($url);
    $url = preg_replace('~[^-a-z0-9_]+~', '', $url); // keep only letters, numbers, '_' and separator
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: You might want to post a full answer rather than just a link in case the linked page goes down.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you'll want your URL to have only 0-9 and a-z, and make sure that everything is lowercase. Replace spaces with dashes (-), and strip the rest of the gibberish.

SO pretty much has it figured out.